# How can the foreign field shows the name instead of its id?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In my models.py, there are two model, the `AvailableArea` has a foreign field refer to `AddressRegion`:

```
class AddressRegion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class AvailableArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    addressregion = models.ForeignKey(AddressRegion, default=1, related_name='availableareas', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the serializers.py, I serialize all the fields:

```
class AvailableAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    region
    """
    class Meta:
        model = AvailableArea
        fields = "__all__"
```

In the views.py:

```
class AddressRegionListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AddressRegionSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = AddressRegion.objects.all()
```

The rest framework data is like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "st-01",
        "addressregion": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "tg-02",
        "addressregion": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "sx-01",
        "addressregion": 3
    }
]
```

I want the `addressregion` not shows the addressregion's `id`, but shows the addressregion's `name`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class AvailableAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    addressregion_name= serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='addressregion.name')

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableArea
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'addressregion_name')
```

Answer (score 6):

just add the following code in your serializer:

```
addressregion_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
```

#should be like the following

```
class AvailableAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):

addressregion_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()

class Meta:
    model = AvailableArea
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'addressregion__name')
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is `read_only`. In other words, although it will bring the string representation to the endpoint you wont be able to update and create.

Answer (score 3):

Your serializer should be like this:

```
class AvailableAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
"""
可用地区
"""
class Meta:
    model = AvailableArea
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'addressregion__name')
```

and `queryset` in View should be:

```
queryset = AddressRegion.objects.all().select_related('addressregion')
```

`select_related` will fetch the result by joining both the table. For more info read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)